# Query Unsubscribes for Child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views, sfmc-business-unit, unsubscribe

I would like to get the # of unsubscribes per month for a specific child BU

(1) I queried **_Unsubscribe**  where **EventDate** is within the desired period

(2) I queried **_ListSubscribers**  where **DateUnsubscribed** is within the desired period

--> 1 and 2 return different results:
 for example 5k and the other 10k, so the difference is huge

--> If I query **ENT._Subscribers**, this might be the real count, but this is for all BUs and I need to count the unsubscribes for a specific BU.

In short, I have different counts and seems none is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your unsubscribe settings in the child Business Units is like below:

[image]

You can use the [BusinessUnit Unsubscribe](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_businessunitunsubscribes.htm&type=5) in the Parent BU. This will give you exact unsubscribes for each BU.

Comment: thank you!  All Subscribers is capturing all unsubscribes anyway?